# jQuery show / hide dependant on input info

Tags: jquery

I have an idea of having 3 easy steps to reveal an answer relevant to the information entered in the 3 steps. I am using [this show/hide script](http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/) which is great However what I am looking to do now is when someone selects 'An Umbrella Employee' I want the next question to appear below, likewise if I select 'A Self Employed Sole Trader' I want a different box to appear below then ultimately based on the options entered there is an answer (in this case the relevant scheme)

I can't get my head round how to do this as I am thinking each option has to be remembered in order for the outcome to match the inputted info.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xg8rz/)

Here is code

html

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/3-step-sfinder.png" width="968" height="100"  class="show_hide" alt="3 steps" /></a>

<div class="slidingDiv">
<img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/step1.png" width="60" height="58"  class="show_hide" alt="step 1" />
<font color=white><strong><h3>I want to work as:</h3></strong></font> <a href="#"  class="show_hide"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/umbrella-emp.png" width="389" height="58" class="show_hide"  alt="umbrella employee" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/self-employed.png" style="float:right; width="473"  height="58" class="show_hide" alt="umbrella employee" /></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

css

```
.slidingDiv {
height:160px;
width:928px;
background-color: #84CFF4;
padding:20px;
margin-top:5px;
border-bottom:5px solid #84CFF4;
}

.show_hide {
display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your problem right!
But why you don't give the links an ID and then check

```
$("#umbrella").live("click", function() {
 shownext;
})
$("#self").live("click", function() {
 showanother;
})
```

and for further steps you make an if (... is shown)

I hope I got your question right.

Comment: I think you got my question right, is there any way you could edit my jsfiddle with this so I can see how it should look? http://jsfiddle.net/Xg8rz/

Comment: Thanks softsdev but I don't really know enough about JS to know how to  make a new div appear below as opposed to the alert message.

Comment: Presumably I need to replace the alert line with something that points it at a new div with the next option?

Comment: ah! I'm struggling to get my head around it as I was then in a position where I was unsure what clicks to open what and was all mixed up. Currently the div won't even stay open, it opens the nest box but then quickly jumps back?? http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/test474837584758.asp#

Comment: Incidentally I'm using softsdev's fiddle as got confused with yours Wikunia.

Comment: Chrome says that this object has no method 'live' try a single 'click' pls.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. One single click in Safari, FF or IE has same result. By default the box is open (ie. step 2 is revealed straight away) plus it opens then quickly closes again. I saw that error in chrome but wasn't sure what that meant.

Comment: I mean instead of live('click', function( this => click(function(

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. That has fixed the 'auto close' issue. Issue now is trying to work out how to open up a new div when 'Umbrella employee' is selected for example. Doing it the way I thought just opens everything by default with none of the images being links. I updated the jsfiddle to show you how i had it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xg8rz/5/ this one? I don't know what this  $('#question_1').after$(".slidingDiv3").slideToggle(); ? http://api.jquery.com/after/ Maybe this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Xg8rz/6/ ;)

Comment: You are correct again although could you have look now? I thought I was madking progress but guess I got carried away. i have created a lot more divs but they all seem to be visible straight away. What have i done wrong? Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xg8rz/7/

Comment: I think I am maing a mess of it and getting my own code mixed up with yours as I notice all have div id of 'question 1' yet no sign of that in my JS!